# Multi-stage build - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

My multi-stage build isn't finding the `/assets/css` directory when it is time to copy it. What do I need to change?

## Docker version

Version 17.06.0-ce-mac17 (18432)

Channel: edge

4bb7a7dfa0

## myimage:sass Image that I use in the multi-stage build

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1-slim

RUN mkdir /assets
VOLUME /assets

RUN gem install sass
ENTRYPOINT ["sass"]
```

## Multi-stage build Dockerfile

Note the debugging commands I run on the first image `cd /assets/css && ls && pwd`, the result is shown during the building phase.

```
# Compile Sass
FROM myimage/sass AS builder
COPY app/assets/sass /assets/sass
RUN sass --update --force --sourcemap=none --stop-on-error /assets/sass:/assets/css &&\
  # sass directory isn't needed
  rm -r assets/sass &&\
  # debugging: check /assets/css exists inside the container
  cd /assets/css && ls && pwd

FROM alpine:3.6
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /app/logs
VOLUME ["/app/logs"]
COPY --from=builder /assets/css /app/assets/css
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["./bin/bash"]
Raw
```

## Output of `docker build -t myimage:css .`

Notice the output of `cd /assets/css && ls && pwd` on step 3/11 showing the `/assets/css` directory exists and it has a `main.css` file inside

```
Step 1/11 : FROM myimage:sass AS builder
 ---> 7c6662186d55
Step 2/11 : COPY app/assets/sass /assets/sass
 ---> 76b5d86846b8
Removing intermediate container ee74d16617b4
Step 3/11 : RUN sass --update --force --sourcemap=none --stop-on-error /assets/sass:/assets/css &&  rm -r assets/sass &&  cd /assets/css && pwd
 ---> Running in 83dc591edc5c
  directory /assets/css
      write /assets/css/main.css
main.css
/assets/css
 ---> 3939f46fb355
Removing intermediate container 83dc591edc5c
Step 4/11 : FROM alpine:3.6
 ---> 7328f6f8b418
Step 5/11 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> 19ad596f9fc1
Removing intermediate container 790fac2040f1
Step 6/11 : RUN mkdir /app/logs
 ---> Running in cb66151a4694
 ---> 18d6c4970d04
Removing intermediate container cb66151a4694
Step 7/11 : VOLUME /app/logs
 ---> Running in b8a98a38a054
 ---> fa68603ccf30
Removing intermediate container b8a98a38a054
Step 8/11 : COPY --from=builder /assets/css /app/assets/css
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0ddcc250ed9c4eb1de46305e62cb2303274b027b2c9b0ddd09471fce3c3ed619/assets/css: no such file or directory
```

So why can't `/assets/css` be copied into the final image? Why can't the Docker engine find it?

Comment: What version of Docker are you using? Are you using 17.06CE or 17.05CE edge? If you're using an older version, multistage build would not be supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
VOLUME /assets
```

Each build step is a new running container. Each new container will discard whatever drops in the unnamed volume.

Check that with:

```
RUN sass --update --force --sourcemap=none --stop-on-error /assets/sass:/assets/css &&\
  # sass directory isn't needed
  rm -r assets/sass
RUN cd /assets/css && ls && pwd
```

(A separate RUN)

Comment: Very interesting! I fixed the problem by compiling the Sass source files to a directory outside of the Docker unnamed volume (`/css` instead of `/assets/css`). Thank you.